# how to disable SSL in react native expo in fetch or axios API call

Tags: react-native, ssl, axios, fetch, expo

I am trying to disable SSL in react native expo

here is what I have tried

```js
import * as https from "https"

const agent = new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
});

let response = await axios(options, { httpsAgent: agent });
```

But its throwing an error on npm start

> While trying to resolve module `https` from file `D:\work\ALPHA OBS\gosi\app\screens\Authentication\signIn.js`, the package `D:\work\ALPHA OBS\gosi\node_modules\https\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`D:\work\ALPHA OBS\gosi\node_modules\https\index.js`. Indeed, none of these

Please Guide me over this.